# Convert text to matrix or numpy array and average the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Need to convert the following text to matrix and average it.

```
stat.txt //find the average of multiple occurrence
Node FC NL  SSD    FC NL   SSD FC NL SSD
   0  1  0    0 2500   0 67200  0  0   0
   1 16  0    0 25600  0 67200  0  0   0
   
Node FC NL  SSD    FC NL   SSD FC NL SSD
   0  1  0    0 35600  0 7200  0  0   0
   1  6  0    0 35600  0 7200  0  0   0
```

FC NL SSD are all values for NODE0 and NODE1.
These values needs to be added and averaged out. Since the text has 2 occurance of the block. I need to add and average and display in the same format as: (but with average valves)

Result should  be something like this:-

```
Node FC NL  SSD    FC NL   SSD FC NL SSD
   0  ## Average values corresponding to NODE0 ##
   1 ## Average values corresponding to NODE1 ##
```

I try to open the text and format:-

```
with open('stat.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read().split()
```

This gives me a list:-

```
 ['Node', 'FC', 'NL', 'SSD', 'FC', 'NL', 'SSD', 'FC', 'NL', 'SSD', '0', '1', '0', '0', '25600', .....

array = np.array(contents)
#print(array)
shape = (10, 6)
res = np.shape(array)
print(res)
```

With the above code i am trying to format it as a Matrix to add and average alternate rows. BUT not able to get the right format.
ANY better way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of lists by:

- make an empty list
- iterate over the lines of the file
- if a line starts with `'Node'` skip it
- if not, split the line and convert the items in the resultant list to numbers

  - append this list to the list you created at the beginning
- when the file iteration stops, feed the list of lists to `numpy.array`.